# Prove $\chi(G) \leq 1+\max\{\delta(H):H \text{ is an induced subgraph} \}$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove that for graph any simple graph $G$ we have: $\chi(G) \leq 1+\max\{\delta(H):H \text{ is an induced subgraph} \}$.

Take $G$ and remove any vertex $v$ with degree less than $\chi(G)-1$. Do the same in $G-v$ and continue this process until no vertex has degree less than $\chi(G)-1$. The graph you are left with is an an induced subgraph $H$ with $\delta(H) \geq \chi(G) - 1$.

How can I prove that this algorithm with terminate. Or is there a simpler way to look at it?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $k=1+\max\{\delta(H):H \text{ is an induced subgraph} \}$, we can show that $G$ can be coloured by $k$ colours greedily.

We start from colouring an arbitrary vertex by some colour from $\{1,\dots,k\}$. If an induced subgraph $H$ has already a feasible $k$-colouring, then pick a vertex not in $H$, then $v$ is at most adjacent to $k-1$ vertices in $H$, hence we can find a colour from $\{1,\dots,k\}$ such that together with the colouring of $H$ we have a feasible $k$-colouring for induced subgraph $H+v$. Hence, the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you be a little more precise? How do we know if $H$ already has a feasible colouring? Also why is $v$ adjacent to at most $k-1$ vertices in $H$.

Comment: We are using induction then. $v$ is adjacent to at most $k-1$ vertices in $H$ because $\max\{\delta(H):H\textrm{ is an induced subgraph}\}=k-1$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a fool. From what I can tell you are suggesting that if $v$ is connected to $k$ vertices in $H$ we can construct an induced subgraph with $\delta(H) > k-1$. But I can't see why this is true since $\delta(H)$ is a minimum degree.

Comment: You cannot see why it is true, because it is not true. If it is true, then it would contradict the definition of $k$.

Comment: So I used induction on the order of $G$. Pull off a vertex with degree less then $k-1$, which is possible because of our definition of $k$. Therefore $G-v$ is $k$ colurable, as a result of our inuduction hypothesis, and $v$ has less than $k$ neighbours so there is a left over colour for $v$.

Comment: Actually, instead of "induction", I prefer to see it as some algorithm. The algorithm is just order the vertices like $v_1,\dots,v_n$, then colour them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\max\limits_{H \subseteq G} \delta(H) +1 = k + 1$ many colors, and say $|G| = n$. Define $H_n = G$. Starting from $i=n$, choose $v_i \in H_i$ such that $d_{H_i}(v_i) = \delta(H_i)$, and define $H_{i-1} = H_{i} - v_i$ for every $i = 2,...,n$. Note that $V(H_i) = \{v_1, ..., v_i\}$ for any $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Consider a greedy coloring of $G$ with the ordering $v_1, v_2,...v_n$. For every $i \leq n$, there are at most $k$ previously colored vertices that are adjacent to $v_i$, since $d_{H_i}(v_i) \leq \max\limits_{H \subseteq G} \delta(H) =k$. Therefore, there exists an available color for $v_i$, and so  $\chi(G) \leq k+1$.